# Can the new "Following" feature be expanded to show up on the Activity page?

Tags: feature-request, follow-post

I really like the new "Following" feature! In addition, it would be helpful to see a list of those questions being followed for easy reference, should I come across answers when studying.

On the *Activity* page, there is a line that includes:

Summary 
Answers 
Questions 
Tags 
Badges 
Favorites 
**Following**

Would it be possible for "Following" to be added to this line showing posts followed? I realize, now, that I could have clicked "Favorite" also when choosing to "Follow", but it's too late for the several already selected.

Comment: It will be, see point 1.  in the linked question.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that in the search. Thanks!